# gtk# adding widgets on button click

Tags: c#, gtk#

I just started using gtk# and I'm having some trouble with a simple problem.  When I started a new project, I used MainWindow's Designer to create a basic UI with hbox/vbox and created an "Add Row" button and a 1-line table consisting of the headers of the table.

My problem is, on button click, I can't figure out how to dynamically add a row to my table.

Side note: My table in the Designer is labeled "table4", but I can't figure out how to access it.  I figure once I can get help on how to properly access it, there should be an AddRow function where I can specify the height, margins, etc?

Thank you for your help.

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using Gtk;

namespace PMA
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Application.Init ();

            //create main window
            MainWindow win = new MainWindow ();

            Application.Run ();
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.cs:

```
using System;
using Gtk;
public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
{
    public MainWindow () : base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        Build ();
    }

    protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Application.Quit ();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }

    private void AddButtonPressHandler (object obj, EventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This works, but can't figure out how to dynamically add a row to MainWindow's table");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solves your problem but I think you can simply increase the NRows property. Put this instead of your AddButtonPressHandler method in MainWindow.cs:

```
private void AddButtonPressHandler (object obj, EventArgs args)
{
       table4.NRows ++;
}
```

I hope it will work right.